# How display table from combobox

Tags: c#

Hi i have combobox with Table names. I would like to display selected table on button click. How to do it? This is code of my combobox

```
Con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM sys.tables", Con);
SqlDataReader rdr;
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
dt.Load(rdr);
wczytywanie.ValueMember = "name";
wczytywanie.DataSource = dt;
Con.Close();
```

now i would like to display these tables in dataGridView after button click.This is not working.

```
            Con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from sys.tables where name=@name", Con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("name", wczytywanie.SelectedValue.ToString());
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            Dane.DataSource = dt;
            Con.Close();
```

Comment: What are you working with WinForms/WPF/something else?

Comment: You should read up on `IDisposable` and the `Dispose` pattern and the `using` statement.  What type is `wczytywanie`?  Take a look at the properties of whatever combo box class you are using.  There's usually a `SelectedItem` property.  What problem are you having?  Are the tables showing in the combo box, or are you having an issue getting the selected one?

Comment: Now it works but how display table in datagridview after selected table on button click

Answer (score 0):

try adding DisplayMember and assign value "name"

```
   wczytywanie.ValueMember = "name";
   wczytywanie.DisplayMember = "name";
```

Comment: Now works thanks but i forgot also to ask how to display now this table in dataGridView after button click?

Comment: simple datagrivew.DataSource =dt; please like my answer if its useful

Comment: I have something liket this but its not working :  
            Con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from sys.tables where name=@name", Con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("name", wczytywanie.SelectedValue.ToString());
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            Dane.DataSource = dt;
            Con.Close();

Comment: Ok you have to use DataSet insted of DataTable Con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from sys.tables where name=@name", Con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("name", wczytywanie.SelectedValue.ToString());
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
            da.Fill(ds);
            Dane.DataSource = ds;
            Con.Close();

Comment: It works but its not displaying my selected value in combobox. I have combobox which shows list of table names from database and now i want to select the table and display it on DataGridView but its not working.It shows me the table with columns object_id, principal_id not the columns from my table

Answer (score 0):

This might do

```
 conn = new MySqlConnection(connectString);
 conn.Open();
 comm = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
 MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
 DataSet DS = new DataSet();
 adapter.Fill(DS);
 advancedDataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
 conn.Close();
```

And to change the column name your sql be like `columnname as 'your preferred column name'`

```
SELECT principal_id as 'Principal ID' from sys.tables where name=@name"
```